# Delete empty members of an PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array called $urls, I want to delete members with value null. I want first submit every member to a function that checks if a member is null, and then I delete the member from array.
E.X.

```
$urls=array();
$url[0]=$_POST['urla'];
$url[1]=$_POST['urlb'];
$url[2]=$_POST['urlc'];
$url[3]=$_POST['urld'];
$url[4]=$_POST['urle'];
```

Well, I want to delete $urls members that has no value (because user didn't fill out the fields ), How can I do it?
thank you for your help

Comment: hint: `array_filter`

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Filtering seems unnecessary here, if you just need the values reindexed you can also do `$url = array_values($_POST);`.  Note that `null` implies that values might not exist, so your current code will generate warnings for every non-existing element. Also note that you can use arrays in html which would probably make all this redundant.

Comment: Thank you all for your amazing help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in below mentioned ways:-

1.`array_filter()`:-

```
<?php
 array_filter($_POST);
 $urls = $_POST;
 print_r($urls);
?>
```

2.Use `array_values()`:-

```
<?php
   $urls = array_values($_POST);
   print_r($urls);
?>
```

Reference:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `array_filter()`, which conveniently handles this for you:

```
<?php
print_r(array_filter($urls));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
$urls = array_filter($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the request post members like following

```
if(isset($_POST['urla']) && $_POST['urla'] != '') 
{
    $url[0]=$_POST['urla'];
}
```

if not working please send me more inputs.

Comment: Question is about using custom function to check if array item is empty. Where is it in your answer?